# Looping through certain files in a folder and running command on them while and also change the file name

Tags: bash, terminal

beginner here. I want to write a simple script for use in the bash terminal, but I don't know how to make it. The gist is that I have a folder filled with different files, some .foo, some .bar, etc. I want to create a script that takes all the .foo files and perform a command on them, but in the same line rename them so that the output file is named file.baz.

For example:
command -i file.foo -o file.baz for all .foo files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

## Renaming

You can use the [`rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) command:

```
$ rename .foo .baz *.foo
```

Note that on some systems `rename` points to [`prename`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/prename/) which uses a different syntax:

```
$ prename 's/.foo$/.baz' *.foo
```

Use `man rename` to find out which one you have.

## Looping over files and running a command on each of them

You can provide the file list directly on the command line, using a [`globbing pattern`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html):

```
$ your_script *.foo
```

Your script can then iterate over the list like this (using your command's usage):

```
for file in "$@"; do
    your_command -i "$file" -o "${file%.*}.baz"
done
```

`${file%.*}` resolves as the name of the file without its extension (`file.foo -> file`). More information on string manipulation is available [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: `for command in "$@"`, of course, my bad. I didn't know about the `command` built-in, will look into it, thanks

Comment: Looks good. Only thing I might add is a pointer on how to generate an output file name at the same time, ie. `for file in *.foo; do your_command -i "$file" -o "${file%.foo}.baz"; done` or such.